# Converting C++ Bit Pattern to Java

Tags: java, c++, bit

I am converting a C++ program to Java and got completely stuck in the following method which blew my mind. Would you be kind enough to explain what this method is doing?

```
long TSBCA::GetSignedValue(const NDataString &value)
    {
       static NDataString s;    
       s = value;

       long multiplier(1);
       size_t len(s.Len());
       if (len != 0)
       {
          if (s[0] >= (char)0xB0 && s[0] <= (char)0xB9)
          {
             s[0] &= 0x7F; //Bit Pattern: 0111 1111
             multiplier = -1;
          }
          else if (s[len - 1] >= (char)0xB0 && s[len - 1] <= (char)0xB9)
          {
             s[len - 1] &= 0x7F; //Bit Pattern: 0111 1111
             multiplier = -1;
          }
          else
             multiplier = 1;
       }
       else
          multiplier = 1;
       return s.ToLong() * multiplier;
    }
```

EDIT:

My initial Java version:

```
private long getSignedValue(final String value){

       byte[] bytes = value.getBytes();
       int length = bytes.length;
       long multiplier = 1L;

       if (bytes.length > 0){
          if (bytes[0] >= (char)0xB0 && bytes[0] <= (char)0xB9){


             bytes[0] &= 0x7F; //Bit Pattern: 0111 1111
             multiplier = -1;
          }
          else if (bytes[length - 1] >= (char)0xB0 && bytes[length - 1] <= (char)0xB9)
          {
              bytes[length - 1] &= 0x7F; //Bit Pattern: 0111 1111
             multiplier = -1;
          }
          else
             multiplier = 1;
       }
       else
          multiplier = 1;
       return Long.parseLong(Arrays.toString(bytes))* multiplier;
}
```

Did I do it right?

Comment: NDataString?  Isn't that Objective C?

Comment: Don't you want to isolate the problem a bit instead of posting your company's code online?

Comment: BTW, if this blew your mind because it appears complicated and convoluted, good!  I wouldn't call it an example of good, clear code.

Answer (score 1):

It's taking a byte string (i.e. not text) and converting to it a long.  It relies on many implementation specific things, and appears broken: it's extracting the sign bit from two different places.  Another issue is the needless non-reentrancy (caused by the static variable).

Comment: If this is code being converted, it's fair to assume that it works and is not necessarily "broken".  The sign implementation may be a strange protocol that you're not expecting, but that doesn't mean it's broken, just awkward.

Comment: This is why I said it appears broken, obviously I don't have the exact spec to which it's written.

Comment: Could you please take a look at the EDIT if I have done right? Thank you.

Comment: Alex: Sorry, I'm not familiar enough with Java to know if you've run into any corner cases.  At a glance, it does look right, since you copied everything down to the multiple superfluous `else multipler = 1`, but you should have someone else look at it.

Answer (score 1):

```
s[0] &= 0x7F;
```

means bit-and `s[0]` with hex `7F` or in other words, strip the sign bit off the byte value.
same with `s[len-1]`, so it:

- takes a numerical string, where the first or the last digit has a sign bit added (`0x30` - `0x39` == `'0'` - `'9'` and `0xB0` - `0xB9` is the same range with the `0x80` bit set.)
- strips that sign bit, remembering it as multiplier
- interprets the numerical string argument using the multiplier to set the sign
- returns that value

**Edit**:

Reviewing your code leads me to the following remarks:

- it does not work as intended, be sure to write some JUnit tests for new code to check that they do what you expect
- place the magic numbers in separate constants
- use `byte` constants when comparing to bytes (sign issues)
- the dangling else's should get braces and in this case are unneeded
- use `new String(byte[])` to reconstruct the string, not the Arrays utility class.

This leads me to this version:

```
// Bit Pattern: 0111 1111
private static final int BYTE_7F = 0x7F;

// '0' with sign bit set
private static final byte BYTE_NEGATIVE_0 = (byte) 0xB0;

// '9' with sign bit set
private static final byte BYTE_NEGATIVE_9 = (byte) 0xB9;


private long getSignedValue(String value) {

    byte[] bytes = value.getBytes();
    final int length = bytes.length;
    long multiplier = 1;

    if (0 < length) {
        if (bytes[0] >= BYTE_NEGATIVE_0 && bytes[0] <= BYTE_NEGATIVE_9) {

            bytes[0] &= BYTE_7F; 
            multiplier = -1;

        } else if (bytes[length - 1] >= BYTE_NEGATIVE_0 && bytes[length - 1] <= BYTE_NEGATIVE_9) {
            bytes[length - 1] &= BYTE_7F;
            multiplier = -1;
        }
    }

    return Long.parseLong(new String(bytes)) * multiplier;
}
```

You still have to pay attention to adding correct comments and update the constant names to bring them in line with your documentation terminology.

Comment: Could you please take a look at the EDIT if I have done right? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's testing for some weird version of sign (positive or negative).  If the first or last (but preferably first) character is between `0xB0` and `0xB9`, then hack off the highest order bit of whichever character it was (making it between `0x30` and `0x39`, the digits `'0'` through `'9'`).  Then return the number with a negative sign as normal humans know it.

Comment: Could you please take a look at the EDIT if I have done right? Thank you.